Discrepancy in Decimal Interpretation between Hive and Spark
I'm querying the same Hive table using both Hive and Spark.
Here's the query:
SELECT balance, interest FROM interests WHERE acct_n = 123
Hive:



balance
interest




1000000
233.47



Spark:



balance
interest




1000000
0.0000023347



Both the balance and interest columns are defined as DECIMAL(38, 10) in the table definition. After checking the source system, it appears that the Hive results are correct, while the Spark results are not.
This discrepancy is puzzling. Can anyone shed light on why this might be happening and suggest a way to rectify it?

I found the reason and wanted to share it.
The underlying Parquet file is somehow saved with a different precision, DECIMAL(37, 2), as opposed to the Hive table schema, DECIMAL(38, 10).
Solution: CAST(interest AS DECIMAL(38, 10) before writing it to the table.
